# Exception caught by widgets library _TreeDesignPageState.dispose failed to call super.dispose. in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an app where if I select a specific tree image and tap on it, it will change the default tree image shown on the main page to the chosen tree image.

When I run the app, it works perfectly fine but when I tap on a specific tree image and head back to the main page(which is main_page.dart) there's an error message showing up on my debug console saying

Exception caught by widgets library
_TreeDesignPageState.dispose failed to call super.dispose.
[image: error]

Here's my code that is related to the issue.

## main_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/tree_design_page.dart';
import 'package:app/models/tree_model.dart';

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/green_meadow.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // Background Image
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/green_meadow.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            // Overlay Image
            Positioned(
              bottom: 10,
              left: 105.7,
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage(treeModelList[selectedtreeindex].path),
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## tree_design_page.dart

```
import 'package:app/models/tree_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TreeDesignPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TreeDesignPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<TreeDesignPage> createState() => _TreeDesignPageState();
}

int selectedtreeindex = 0;

class _TreeDesignPageState extends State<TreeDesignPage> with ChangeNotifier {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/landscape1.jpg'), //the background image
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: treeModelList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Clicked ${treeModelList[index].id}!");
                    selectedtreeindex = index;
                    notifyListeners();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(treeModelList[index].path),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 113.7,
                  top: 70,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 184,
                    child: Text(
                      treeModelList[index].title,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And these are the images of the result of my emulator.

[image: result1]
[image: result2]

Comment: Is not an approach that I would encourage, but have you tried to make `selectedtreeindex` static? Here you should use a Provider for state management

Comment: I've tried to learn Provider and implement it but I had no idea how to use Provider in this kind of situation that I was facing so I just ended up using ChangeNotifier instead

Comment: You are on a good track then. Try to implement the example from here: https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple